# SQL Server query with o lower limit for the rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I´m looking for a T-SQL query that will only give a result set if the rowcount exceeds a certain limit.

Like giving an upper bound with the `TOP` - clause.

Pseudo code:

```sql
select * 
from customer 
where count(*) > 100   

or   

select at_least(100) *
from customer
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, please don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*) from t) > 100;
```

Or an `if` statement:

```
if (select count(*) from t) > 100
    select t.*
    from t;
```

Note:  Performance can be improved by using a subquery that looks for only 100 rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*) from (select top (101) t.* from t) > 100;
```

This only counts up to 101.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very efficiently with a window function:

```sql
select t.*
from (
    select *,
        count(*) over () countRows
    from t
) t
where countRows > 100;
```